# Extract sentences from a json file using bash

Tags: json, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a json file with the following contents:

```
"1034280": {
    "transcript": ["1040560",
    "Ok, so what Akanksha is saying is that..."],
    "interaction": "Student Question"
},
"1041600": {
    "transcript": ["1044860",
    "this is also not correct because it will take some time."],
    "explain": "Describing&Interpreting"
},
"1046800": {
    "transcript": ["1050620",
    "So, what you have to do is, what is the closest to the answer?"],
    "question": "FocusingInformation"
},
```

I want to extract the transcript sentences and concatenate them.

For ex. I want the output as:

```
"Ok, so what Akanksha is saying is that..." "this is also not correct because it will take some time." "So, what you have to do is, what is the closest to the answer?"
```

Comment: If you **must** use bash for this (and it's better to switch to a language with a native JSON parser), `jsawk` is your friend.

Comment: +1 to Charles' comment: `ruby -rjson -e 'JSON.parse(STDIN.read).each_pair {|k,v| print %q{"%s" } % v["transcript"][1]}'` works, if the sample text is tweaked into valid JSON.

Comment: Your `json` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

With the caveats

- You should really use a JSON parsing library as indicated in the comments
- This will likely only work if your data exactly matches the question
- I'll leave deciphering the awk up to you as you didn't specify what you've tried

When the input data is in a file called `data`:

```
awk -F"]," 'BEGIN { ORS="" } /"transcript":/ {p=1} NF==2 && p=1 { sub( /^[[:space:]]*"/, (++i==1?"":" ")"\"", $1 ); print $1; p=0 } END { print "\n" }' data
```

outputs:

```
"Ok, so what Akanksha is saying is that..." "this is also not correct because it will take some time." "So, what you have to do is, what is the closest to the answer?"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{/,+2{//,+1d;s/^\s*\|],\s*$//g;H;};$!d;x;s/\n//;y/\n/ /' file
```